# Table multicols

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I need do this table. Do you have any tips?

[image]

Comment: Welcome. // Have a look here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables . It's also a good idea to check manuals of packages: https://ctan.org/pkg/multicol .

Comment: Of course I have already read it. Problem for me is 2rows in first column and 3 rows in third column at fixed width

Comment: Besides providing code of own attempts please provide such info next time. We simply can‘t know…

Answer (score 3):

Might be easiest to treat *every* cell as multirow, even the ones in the final column. Then you can make those two rows, and the ones in the first column three rows, so they're proportional. E.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}

\NewColumnType{n}{Q[c,wd={0.33\textwidth}]}
\Huge\bfseries
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={nnn},
    rows={0.7cm},
    vlines = 2pt,
    hlines = {1}{-}{2pt}
    }
\SetCell[r=3]{c}{1} & \SetCell[r=6]{c}{3} & \SetCell[r=2]{c}{4} \\
& & \\
& & \SetCell[r=2]{c}{5}\\
\SetCell[r=3]{c}{2} & & \\
& & \SetCell[r=2]{c}{6} \\
& &
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

I'm using [tabularray](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) for easy control over things like row height.

[image: table with unevenly balanced columns]

Comment: It works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Non-`tabularray` example

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcommand\mr[2]{\multirow{#1}*[-1pt]{#2}}
\begin{document}
\bgroup
  \setlength\arrayrulewidth{1.2pt}
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{0.65}
  \centering%
  \bfseries
  \begin{tabular}{|*3{C{1cm}|}}
    \hline
    \mr{3}{1} & \mr{6}{3} & \mr{2}{4} \\
              &           &           \\ \cline{3-3}
              &           & \mr{2}{5} \\ \cline{1-1}
    \mr{3}{2} &           &           \\ \cline{3-3}
              &           & \mr{2}{6} \\
              &           &           \\ \cline{3-3}
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \par
\egroup
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same as [frabjous](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/411/frabjous) but with the new interface command of tabularray.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
        hlines={2pt},
        vlines={2pt},
        rows={0.7cm},
        columns={c,.33\linewidth,font=\Huge\bfseries},
        cell{1}{1}={r=3,c=1}{},
        cell{4}{1}={r=3,c=1}{},
        cell{1}{2}={r=6,c=1}{},
        cell{1}{3}={r=2,c=1}{},
        cell{3}{3}={r=2,c=1}{},
        cell{5}{3}={r=2,c=1}{},
        }
    1 & 3 & 4 \\
      &   &   \\
      &   & 5 \\
    2 &   &   \\
      &   & 6 \\
      &   &
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following tabular constructed with the classical tools of LaTeX:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*{3}{w{c}{8mm}|}}
\hline
&   & 4 \\
\cline{3-3}
& 3 & 5 \\
\cline{3-3}
&   & 6 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the first code]

Now, if you use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you will have the same output by default. However, `nicematrix` creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, rows and columns of the array. It's now possible to use those nodes with Tikz to divide the first column with a rule drawn by Tikz and put contents in the subcells.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|*{3}{w{c}{8mm}|}}
\hline
&   & 4 \\
\cline{3-3}
& 3 & 5 \\
\cline{3-3}
&   & 6 \\
\hline
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (2.5-|1) -- (2.5-|2) ;
  \node at ($(1-|1)!0.5!(2.5-|2)$) {1} ; 
  \node at ($(2.5-|1)!0.5!(4-|2)$) {2} ; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because of the PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the second code]